# Clojure: Webbit + Ring

Tags: clojure, websocket, compojure, ring

### Context

I just got http://blog.jayfields.com/2011/02/clojure-web-socket-introduction.html working.

I also have ring + compojure working.

### Question:

I would like to use ring ... somehow ... with webbit is this possible?

Thanks!

Comment: Not until webbit expose its feature as a ring middleware

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ring works with web servers via adapters. The most common case is that people want to use jetty, so Ring ships with [a jetty adapter](https://github.com/mmcgrana/ring/blob/master/ring-jetty-adapter/src/ring/adapter/jetty.clj).

In order to use ring with webbit, you'd want to write an adapter for it. Unfortunately, there doesn't seem to be any public webbit adapters already in existence, so you'll likely have to roll your own.

Comment: So, in other words, I want aleph? :-)

Answer (score 3):

Ring defines only request-response cycle, there’s no push in Ring [SPEC](https://github.com/ring-clojure/ring/blob/master/SPEC). You can write webbit ring adapter, but it will only allow you to react to the events happening in browser, without the ability to notify browser from server side. But, you can still do it directly via webbit api, not through ring middleware though.

You can read the same thing at the [aleph](https://github.com/ztellman/aleph/) page:

> Aleph conforms to the interface described by Ring, with one small difference: the request and response are decoupled.